# Open random port number for http request not port 80

Tags: networking, port, http

I am reading book called : Learn Python the hard way.
In ex51 [link](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/python3/ex51.html) it says:

> Connection

" Once a browser knows what protocol you want to use (http), what server you want to talk to (http://test.com/), and what resource on that server to get, it must make a connection. The browser simply asks your operating system (OS) to open a "port" to the computer, usually port 80."

I think it should be random port number from local PC right? the web service is listen to port 80 but our operation system which browser asks to is a random port number not port 80?

Answer (score 1):

Sort of.  Each TCP connection (and http is normally done over TCP) has both a source and destination port. In the case of a web server listening in the default port 80 your computer will send traffic from another port number, but it must they destination port must be port 80.

Comment: Thanks. If local port using port 80 as well, wouldn't it block the port ? Normally I have seen the remote host(server) is using port 80 but local port is whatever os assigned isn't it?

Comment: No, because the connection comprises source IP, Source Port, Destination IP, Destination port, so as long as the destination IP is different traffic to port 80 will not be routed to your list Cal server.

Comment: Thanks. Then how about local pc open two connection via http to same remote server with different url? for example one tap is visiting text.com/index.html then the other tap is visiting text.com/search.html? Assume both of these two locations are under same IP

Comment: (Inoring persistent connections and other optimizations) The source port is all that changes at a TCP level.